# Visual Studio 2022 turn on marking of start and end tags in XML files

Tags: xml, xslt, visual-studio-2022

Coming from Visual Studio 2019, I am used to the editor marking start and end tags in XML/XSLT files when clicking a tag like on this screenshot.

[image]

However this doesn't work for me in Visual Studio 2022. Where can this be turned on? It works fine for .cs files but not XML/XSLT.

Comment: I don't seem to have a marker in XML, neither in VS 2019 (16.11.10) nor in VS 2022 (17.0.6). I wonder whether the greyed out option for "automatic brace completion" has anything to do with that.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Automatic Brace Completion is turned on in my VS2022. But it doesn't change anything whether I turn it on or off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question here. The difference between my VS2019 and VS2022 was that I had ReSharper installed only in VS2019. Once I also installed it in VS2022, the marking of start and end tags worked on my XSLT files. I would think that VS2022 had this functionality it self, but none the less this solved my issue.